# HTML Canvas RGBA stroking

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning canvas and my goal is to draw free-hand. Every example online says that I should call `stroke()` within my `onmousemove`. This works as expected if my color `strokeStyle` has 100% opacity. However if I use `rgba` with `0.3` alpha value, then calling `stroke()` over and over again re-colors the entire path, thus eventually forcing the line to be opaque.

I tried overcoming this by drawing a line, stopping the path, and starting a new one. This worked half way -- the overlapping part of the path would be twice as dark -- which is very problematic if you are using a thick line width.

Lastly -- I moved stroke() to `onmouseup` -- and this works great except that the user cannot see what he's drawing until he releases the mouse.

How can I address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to address this is to remember each and every mousemove coordinate and put them in a list. On each mousemove, you clear the canvas and redraw the entire path plus-the-newest-point onto the canvas.

This will make it look nice like you want.

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/sQLSp/

If you want the canvas to persist between lines you will want to save it to an in-memory canvas at each mouse-up and repaint it at each step. If you want to see what that looks like, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sQLSp/3/

Edit: Example modified for doing it the Opera-tutorial way: http://jsfiddle.net/2vAQE/

Comment: What you say makes sense -- is that really the best way? seems like a waste of resources. I also found this example: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/ it uses clearRect() like you do, but it doesn't actually erase everything... it's confusing

Comment: (I just edited my answer a bit). It might not be the best way, its just the first thing that came to mind. I'll let you know if I think up something more efficient, but the immediate-drawing-surface nature of canvas suggests that this is probably the only way you've got if this is the effect you want. Still, there's probably something clever that I'm not thinking of :)

Comment: Oh, there is another good way! The Opera tutorial is using a temporary second on-screen canvas for the visual feedback, and then it 'commits' that feedback to the normal canvas on mouse-up. That will work just as well!

Comment: Here is the same example modified for doing it the opera way: http://jsfiddle.net/2vAQE/

Comment: I think I can understand your code... now sure how you overlay the two  canvas such that they are pixel perfect of each other. Will this work if both of them are inside a layout div?

Comment: You have to fiddle with the CSS a bit, but it ought to work so long as they are inside of the same DIV

Comment: if I set `lineCap="round"` and `lineWidth=40` I get very strange block-looking lines if I move the mouse slowly. If I move fast, everything works as expected... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's a mitering problem. Set the `lineJoin="round"` also and it will work perfectly.